# Remote Workstation Management

Tags: remote-access, antivirus

I have a small number (less than 5) of standalone workstations (currently running windows 7) for staff who are based in India.

I have 3 requirements to solve here.

1. I need to lock down their systems so they can't accidentally install spyware, unnecessary shareware software, or useless browser plugins
2. I need to shadow their system (e.g remote screen view, without them knowing for randomized spot checks)
3. I need to take active control of their system to help solve problems

I don't mind changing the operating system to a Linux based one if that is better. I also don't want to invest in deploying a centralized Windows Server and a full Windows Network.

Can anyone recommend and software to assist with this?